# Xamarin iOS - specify image to use for button from asset library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following Image asset defined (FSDirectButton)...

[image]

How do I specify a button to use this as it's image in the Xamarin xib designer?

[image]

When I choose the Image option in the properties window all I see are images that are stored in my Images folder.

[image]

I inherited this app which was originally done in a older version of Xamarin iOS, so not sure if that is affecting things or not...

However I want to use the image asset library for my buttons, but I am not sure how to specify in the designer which image to use?  Or do I have to do it runtime in code?

Comment: I do find the same issue too. I can just fix it by using code to set a image to a button like:`MyButton.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("MyImage"), UIControlState.Normal);`

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQJGigHG65M&feature=youtu.be) It can help you, but raise some new bug. Enjoy

Also you can set the Image from Asset catalog in your ViewDidLoad() method.
For example:

```
//get image set from asset catalog
var imageFromBunde = UIImage.FromBundle("ImageSet"); //ImageSet - name of your image set in Asset catalog
myImage.Image = imageFromBundle;
```

Comment: You should really try do include some information in your answer, not just a link to a video.